# Regex get every string from start until new line?

Tags: regex, go

I have a string like this :

```
Name: Yoza Jr
Address: Street 123, Canada
Email: yoza@gmail.com
```

I need get data using regex until new line, for example

Start with `Name:` get `Yoza Jr` until `new line` for name data

so I can have 3 data `Name, Address, Email`

How to Regex get every string from start until new line?

btw I will use it in golang : https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html

Comment: Please include the relevant code you have tried as well.

Comment: I tried it here https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `^.*$` should work, see the [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/0H70K5/1).  This assumes that `.*` would not be running in dot all mode, meaning that `.*` will not extend past the `\r?\n` newline at the end of each line.

If you want to capture the field value, then use:

```
^[^:]+:\s*(\S+)$
```

The quantity you want will be present in the first capture group.

Comment: thanks, what I need is get the value, for example I want to get `Name` with regex `^Name:.*$`, I hope it full-match with `Yoza Jr`

Comment: why I try it in golang https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html, it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the pattern `^(.+):\s*(.*)$`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Q9D4RM/1

Not only will it result in 3 distinct matches for the string given by you, the field name (before the ":") will be read as group 1 of the match, and the value (after the ":") will be read as group 2. So, if you want the key-value pairs, you can just search for groups 1 and 2 for each match.

Please let me know if it's unclear so I can elaborate.

Comment: I tried it using golang, but not work. And I test it to here https://regex-golang.appspot.com/assets/html/index.html

Comment: Are you matching with global and multiline mode? If you go to the same link and try with just "Name: Yoza Jr" it seems to work. There wasn't an option to pass run it in global or multiline mode, and I don't know golang so I'm not sure how to pass those flags to run Regex match. Most languages allow global and multiline like nodejs. Meanwhile, I'll search for a way to do it in golang.